# Capture pattern in python

Tags: python, scraping

I would like to capture the following pattern using python
   `anyprefix-emp-<employee id>_id-<designation id>_sc-<scale id>`

Example data

```
strings = ["humanresourc-emp-001_id-01_sc-01","itoperation-emp-002_id-02_sc-12","Generalsection-emp-003_id-03_sc-10"]
```

Expected Output:

```
[('emp-001', 'id-01', 'sc-01'), ('emp-002', 'id-02', 'sc-12'), ('emp-003', 'id-03', 'sc-10')]
```

How can i do it using python.

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers (click on the tick symbol of one answer). This will mark it as a solved post so it is not left open on the forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also solve this problem by the following ways;

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(emp-.+)_(id-.+)_(sc-.+)")
strings = ["humanresourc-emp-001_id-01_sc-01","itoperation-emp-002_id-02_sc-12","Generalsection-emp-003_id-03_sc-10"]
print([regex.findall(s)[0] for s in strings])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. It's solve my problem.

Comment: I'am happy to know that.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

```
[tuple(s[s.find("-") + 1:].split("_")) for s in strings]
```

## Explanation

Each string has a nice regular format:

1. a description
2. employee number
3. id number
4. 'sc' number      (don't know what that could be)

These attributes are all separated by an underscore: `_`.

You're result doesn't need to description, so find the place of the end of the description and remove it. I find the first hyphen (`-`) then only keep everything after that.

Then I split the remaing string into three strings, using `split("_")`.

This returns the three parts you want, which I then put into a tuple.

I perform this for each string in `strings`.

You can put it in a function like this:

```
def extract_tags(strings):
    result = [tuple(s[s.find("-") + 1:].split("_")) for s in strings]
    return result
```

Here is the output on your test string:

```
[('emp-001', 'id-01', 'sc-01'),
 ('emp-002', 'id-02', 'sc-12'),
 ('emp-003', 'id-03', 'sc-10')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
strings = ["humanresourc-emp-001_id-01_sc-01","itoperation-emp-002_id-02_sc-12","Generalsection-emp-003_id-03_sc-10"]
new_list = []
pattern = '[a-zA-Z]+?[-]{1}(?P<empid>emp-[0-9]{3})_(?P<desid>id-[0-9]{2})_(?P<sclid>sc-[0-9]{2})'
for test_string in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, test_string)
    new_tuple = tuple([m.group('empid'), m.group('desid'), m.group('sclid')])
    new_list.append(new_tuple)
```

Not sure if this gets you exactly what you want, but the regex pattern works on the data provided.

Here is my output:

```
[('emp-001', 'id-01', 'sc-01'), ('emp-002', 'id-02', 'sc-12'), ('emp-003', 'id-03', 'sc-10')]
```

Comment: This is a perhaps a good technical answer, but I would say overkill for the use case. I would still say that this method is a lot more powerful and could be tailored to other more specific and difficult cases, due to the flexibility of regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I like your one-liner.  It is elegant and probably faster than mine.  I went down the `re` path because it looked like the OP was looking for a pattern / named group solution.